# PhantomJS, generated PDF file size is different on local in compare with aws-lambda

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, aws-lambda

I am using PhantomJS to convert web page to PDF. 
When I run the code in my development environment the output file size is around few KB but when I run the same code on AWS-Lambda the output file size is around few MB.

I want to generate a pdf file with the same size of dev environment.

Here is the code I am using for conversion

```
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36';

var url = system.args[1];
var file_name = system.args[2]
var margin = system.args[3];

page.paperSize = {
    format: 'A2',
    orientation: 'portrait',
    margin:  JSON.parse(margin)
};

page.evaluate(function () {
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.innerHTML = '.card-padding{padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 0;}';
    document.body.appendChild(style);
})

page.open(url, function start(status) {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        page.render(file_name, {format: 'pdf'});
        system.stdout.write(file_name)
        phantom.exit();
    }, 5000);
});
```

I also tried to set the page dpi

```
page.open(url, function start(status) {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        page.dpi=72
        page.render(file_name, {format: 'pdf'});
        system.stdout.write(file_name)
        phantom.exit();
    }, 5000);
})
```

but it didn't help. 
You can find the project [here](https://github.com/fartashh/lambda-exportPDF)

Comment: I would start by looking here to determine what the exact file differences are: https://superuser.com/questions/46123/how-to-compare-the-differences-between-two-pdf-files-on-windows

Comment: I used diffpdf in ubuntu but it doesn't give me and actionable information. it looks like in the file with bigger size, the font is a tiny bit smaller.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution is**;

- create a `.fonts` folder
- put the fonts you are using in PDF in `.fonts` folder
- Add enviroment variable to lambda `HOME = /var/task`

it significantly reduces the file size.

**What was the issue**;

PhantomJs v2.1.x on debian and ubuntu at least handles local fonts correctly, i.e, they are embedded in the pdf and therefore rendered on screen in high quality, the text is searchable and selectable and the file size is kept low. For remote webfonts, the text is converted to outlines, fonts are not embedded and text doesn't search and selectable, and makes the file size huge for longer docs.